# UITableView cells on the same row

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

as I say in the title, I'd like to display two or more cells on the same row. I have every cell with a UILabel inside. The labels can have changing width depending on user's input. I'd like to fill a row with many labels as I can. Can someone give me some advice on how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: maybe you are looking for something like a tags list view [github:TagListView](https://github.com/ElaWorkshop/TagListView)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can't. Slightly longer answer: Use a collection view.
Table views are designed to show a single column of cells.

You **can't** make a table view contain multiple cells in a row.

You could probably create a view controller that had side-by-side table views inside it, but it would be awkward and hard to use, and the table views would scroll independently of each other.

If you want multiple cells on the same row, you want a collection view. A collection view is similar to, but more flexible than, a table view.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using a horizontal UIStackView to achieve what you're trying to do. Depends on how dynamic and changeable you need it to be.